# calling nodejs request.end() method before setting up the listeners

Tags: node.js

In the nodejs docs http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect_1 the example code calls request.end() before setting up the listeners(i.e req.on(...) methods). The example code snipet  is shown below.

```
  var req = http.request(options);
  req.end();

  req.on('connect', function(res, socket, head) {
    console.log('got connected!');

    // make a request over an HTTP tunnel
    socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
                 'Host: www.google.com:80\r\n' +
                 'Connection: close\r\n' +
                 '\r\n');
    socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
    socket.on('end', function() {
      proxy.close();
    });
  });
```

If this case doesn't the request ends immediately before the listeners are set and the listeners may never be called at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `req.end()` call is saying that you're done sending the request body to the server (in this case there's no request body), not that the full request/response cycle is complete. Also, `http.request` will defer the start of the connection to the server until the next pass through the run loop to give you a chance to setup your listeners.

So, in essence, it's doing something like this:

1. Create a new request
2. Tell the request that we're done sending the data we're going to send
3. Tell the request to let us know when we connect to the server

*Next Run Loop Pass*

4. Attempt to connect to the server

*After Successful Connection*

5. Send request, etc.